# Windows API to determine Service Pack version

Tags: windows, windows-vista, service, pack

We're working on a device driver for Vista.
There's a known bug in SPO (that was fixed in SP1). We have a workaround that only works in SP0 (and destroys the behavior in SP1).

Is there a Windows API or another way to tell what Service Pack version is installed? (Programmatically).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want the function [GetVersionEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451(VS.85).aspx), in particular the wServicePackMajor and wServicePackMinor members of the associated [OSVERSIONINFOEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724833(VS.85).aspx) structure.

I'm assuming you are doing this internally in your driver and not from a web app or something given the asp.net tag.

Comment: eek. i don't know how that asp.net tag got in there.  Thanks! I looked at this earlier, but I can't believe I missed these fields.